# Scheduled Azure WebJob but NoAutomaticTrigger-Method not invoked

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

This question is related to this one: [Running Azure WebJob without queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438115/running-azure-webjob-without-queue)

My scenario: I just want to write a file each hour into the blob storage and don't need any queue system. From the former question I got this code - which worked fine the first time it is triggered:

```
    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static void DoWork([Blob("container/foobar.txt")] TextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("Hello World " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString())"
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        JobHost host = new JobHost();
        host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("DoWork"));

        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

The website is running with "AlwaysOn=true" and the webjob is "Running" all the time but now the scheduler throws following error - and nothing happens:
"Cannot start a new run since job is already running."

The current result is that the file is only written once. If I switch "AlwaysOn" to false it "works", but it seems dirty because without the Always on the job result is "Aborted".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A job marked as "on demand" must complete. In your case, the problem is the `RunAndBlock` call at the end. If you call that method, the console app never stops (that's why the job "is already running") because `RunAndBlock` is basically a `while(true)` loop.

`RunAndBlock` should be used only for continuous jobs.

Comment: Thanks - works like a charm. I took the "RunAndBlock" from this code example - maybe it should be removed there as well:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/AzureWebJobs/BasicSamples/TableOperations/Program.cs

Comment: Hm... I have to agree that the sample might be confusing. The idea was to deploy that job as continuous, not on demand. I'll see if I can rewrite it. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Should i use host.Start() method to manually trigger a webjob ?